# Python I/O Index out of range, not an off-by-one error (I think)

Tags: python, io

I have this simple code which is really just to help me understand how Python I/O works:

```
inFile = open("inFile.txt",'r')
outFile = open("outFile.txt",'w')
lines = inFile.readlines()

first = True
for line in lines:
    if first == True:
        outFile.write(line)  #always print the header
        first = False
        continue
    nums = line.split()
    outFile.write(nums[3] + "\n") #print the 4th column of each row
outFile.close()
```

My input file is something like this:

```
#header
34.2 3.42 64.56 54.43 3.45
4.53 65.6 5.743 34.52 56.4
4.53 90.8 53.45 134.5 4.58
5.76 53.9 89.43 54.33 3.45
```

The output prints out into the file just as it should but I also get the error:

```
    outFile.write(nums[3] + "\n")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm assuming this is because it has continued to read the next line although there is no longer any data?

Comment: What do you expect num[6] to be?

Comment: nums[6] would refer to a column that doesn't exist in your input file

Comment: BTW, use a boolean for `first`, not an integer - it's just a style thing, but one you should embrace

Comment: @Mark Sorry, I goofed. I have fixed it now. When I simplified the code the post here I forgot to change the '6' to a '3'. It should be accurate now.

Comment: What is the value on line when the error occurs

Comment: My guess at this point is that your input file has lines that aren't of the form you're expecting - maybe there are blank lines at the end of the file?  if I were you, I'd try and print out nums just to see what it contains.  Personally, I'd move your header line handling logic outside of the loop, and just read and write it before starting the loop - alleviates the need for an if-then on each loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have already answered your question. Here is a better way to "always print out the file header", avoiding testing for `first` at every iteration:

```
with open('inFile.txt', 'r') as inFile, open('outFile.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(inFile.readline()) #always print the header
    for line in inFile:
        nums = line.split()
        if len(nums) >= 4: #Checks to make sure a fourth column exists.
            outFile.write(nums[3] + "\n") #print the 4th column of each row
```

A couple things are going on here:

```
with open('inFile.txt', 'r') as inFile, open('outFile.txt', 'w') as outFile:
```

The `with` expression is a convenient way to open files because it automatically closes the files even if an exception occurs and the with block exits early.

*Note: In Python 2.6, you will need to use two `with` statements, as support for multiple contexts was not added until 2.7. e.g:*

```
with open(somefile, 'r') as f:
    with open(someotherfile, 'w') as g:
        #code here.
```

---

```
outFile.write(inFile.readline()) #always print the header
```

The `file` object is an iterator that gets *consumed*. When `readline()` is called, the buffer position advances forwards and the first line is returned.

---

```
for line in inFile:
```

As mentioned before, the `file` object is an iterator, so you can use it directly in a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you, this make a lot of sense.  I'm getting a syntax error on the comma in the first line.  The one between inFile and open.

Comment: @whatsherface: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The error shows that in your source code you have the following line:

```
outFile.write(nums[6] + "\n")
```

Note that the `6` there is different from the `3` you show in your question. You may have two different versions of the file.

It fails because `nums` is the result of splitting a line and in your case it contains only 5 elements:

```
for line in lines:
    # ...
    # line is for example "34.2 3.42 64.56 54.43 3.45"
    nums = line.split() 
    print len(nums)
```

You can't index past the end of a list.

You also may have an error in your code. You write the header, then split it and write one element from it. You probably want an if/else.

```
for line in lines:
    if first == 1: 
        # do something with the header
    else:
        # do something with the other lines
```

Or you could just handle the header separately before you enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are processing the "header line" just like the rest of the data. I.e., even though you identify the header line,  you *don't* skip its processing. I.e., you don't avoid `split()`'ing it further down in the loop which causes the run-time error.

To fix your problem simply insert a `continue` as shown:

```
first = True
for line in lines:
    if first == True:
       outFile.write(line)  #always print the header
       first = False
       continue   ## skip the rest of the loop and start from the top 
    nums = line.split()
    ...
```

that will bypass the rest of the loop and all will work as it should.

The output file `outFile.txt` will contain:

```
#header
54.43
34.52
134.5
54.33
```

And the 2nd problem turned out having blank lines at the end of the input file (see discussion in comments below)

*Notes*: You could restructure  your code, but if you are not interested in doing that, the simple fix above lets you keep all of your present code, and only requires the addition of the one line. As mentioned in other posts, it's worth looking into using `with` to manage your open files as it will also close them for you when you are done or an exception is encountered.

Comment: Thank you, this is the easiest solution. My output is printing correctly, however I'm still getting the same list index out of range error.

Comment: @whatsherface That is very odd, since I ran this program and posted the output here. Can you check and make sure your input file *doesn't* have any empty blank lines at the end?

Comment: @whatsherface I bet that's the problem, I just added a blank line at the end of my file and got the error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @whatsherface In which case the two problems were:  processing the header line like the rest of the data (as mentioned above), and blank lines in the input file (which are hard to spot unless you suspect them there)

Comment: Oh crap I'm an idiot.  That was the problem.  Sorry guys!  Well I at least learned some better coding practices!  Thanks everyone!